# Как заставить выполнять все действия во время итераций последовательно?

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, async-await, асинхронность

В данный момент пишу бекэнд на Node.JS.
Мне необходимо совершать представленные ниже операции применяя каждый элемент этого массива. Написав код ниже я пришёл к выводу, что map выполняется не в той последовательности, которая мне нужна — отсюда ошибки.
У меня есть массив ссылок `arr`.
В данный момент код исполняется в таком порядке:
Исходная ссылка до условия `url[0]`;
Исходная ссылка до условия `url[1]`;
Начало негативного условия;
Исходная ссылка в негативном условии `url[0]`;
Начало негативного условия;
Исходная ссылка в негативном условии `url[1]`;
Конец негативного условия;
Конец негативного условия.

Нужный порядок:
Исходная ссылка до условия `url[0]`;
Проверка условия для `url[0]`;
Исходная ссылка до условия `url[1]`;
Проверка условия для `url[1]`.

Вывод значений, должно получится:

```
[
  { vat: vat, url: url },
  { vat: vat, url: url }
]
```

В данном коде использован `puppeteer`, всё что относится к нему начинается на: `await page`.

Собственно код:

```
const promises = arr.map(async (url, key) => {
    console.log('Исходная ссылка до условия ' + url);
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitForSelector('td.sp-properties-form__value');

    if (await page.$eval('td.title-card-page__right-column > table.company-stats > tbody > tr.company-stats__item:nth-child(2) td.company-stats-item__label span.text-mutted', el => el.textContent) === "Головная компания") {
      console.log('Начало позитивного условия');
      const newurl = await page.$eval('td.title-card-page__right-column > table.company-stats > tbody > tr.company-stats__item:nth-child(2) span.white-space-normal > a', el => el.href);
      console.log('Новая ссылка ' + newurl)
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, getRandom()));
      await page.goto(newurl);
      await page.waitForSelector('td.sp-properties-form__value');
      const vat = await page.$eval('td.company-reg-codes span.sp-delimited-list__item:nth-child(2) span.entity-reg-code__value span', el => el.textContent);
      res[key] = { vat: vat, url: newurl };
      console.log('Конец позитивного условия');
    } else {
      console.log('Начало негативного условия');
      console.log('Исходная ссылка в негативном условии ' + url)
      const vat = await page.$eval('td.company-reg-codes span.sp-delimited-list__item:nth-child(2) span.entity-reg-code__value span', el => el.textContent);
      res[key] = { vat: vat, url: url };
      console.log('Конец негативного условия');
    }
    return res[key]
  })
  const result = await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log(result)
```

Comment: Замените `map` на `for`. В `map` запускается сразу много асинхронных функций подряд, он не ожидает разрешения `async` в аргументе. А `for` будет ожидать все `await`-ы до следующей итерации. То есть вам нужно не параллельное исполнение с последовательным началом как сейчас, а полностью последовательное.

Comment: Да, делал так, но как тогда сделать return?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, разобрался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам посоветовали в комментарии, попробуйте заменить

```js
const promises = arr.map(async (url, key) => {
  // ...
  return res[key];
});
```

на что-то вроде

```js
const promises = [];
for (const [url, key] of arr.entries) {
  // ...
  promises.push(res[key]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, как и сам не догадался!))